# Access google cloud shell through MobaXterm

Tags: google-cloud-storage, mobaxterm

Can I access google cloud shell through MobaXterm?
I am an entry level programmer so a step by step (okay if not too detailed) explaination will be much appreciated. That's just because I like MobaXterm interface and I can quickly upload a file fro my computer onto the google cloud.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks In advance

Comment: I have similar query. But I was wondering if I could simply use the cloud shell that pops up on dashboard to upload files onto google cloud database. Instead of using MobaXTerm

Comment: take a look https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4fJ3m_nAJ0

Answer (score -3):

**Pre-requisite**: gcloud must be installed on Windows

**Navigate** MobaXterm's Settings>Configurations>Local shell settings.

**Enable** "Use Windows PATH"

[image]

**Verify:**
gcloud -h

[image]